# Can I still update my camera-ready submission on IEEE-CPS after the deadline?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, ieee, deadlines

I have already submitted the camera-ready version of my paper to a conference within the deadline. However, although it is now multiple days past the deadline, the submission is still open on the IEEE-CPS site with the option to edit my submission.

I would like to update my submission (to correct a minor mistake), but I am not sure if I should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they permit it then feel free to do so. The worst that would happen is that the update is rejected and the current version is published. Especially so, if they say "option to edit".

Of course, an edit that would seem to require another round of review or that changes a major result will have serious issues. But a "minor mistake" shouldn't disrupt things until they "go to press".